# How does the electric field pulse propagate during a change in the magnetic vector potential?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

The electric field in terms of the electric scalar potential, and the magnetic vector potential is:

$E = -\nabla\phi - \frac{\partial A}{\partial t}$, where $A$ is such that $B = \nabla \times A$.

In this field configuration:

[image]

a change in the poloidal current sheet $J$ will cause a change to propagate through $A$ and a corresponding electric field pulse, coextensive with the changing $A$.  Is this $E$ field accompanied by a non-0 $B$ field other than the one already inside of $J$?  Does the change propagate at the speed of light?

Comment: Can you write down a functional form for the "propagating electric field pulse"?

Comment: Rob, That would be another StackExchange question.  A related question has already been asked, but not answered:

"Measurement of speed of static electric field propagation?"
http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/101413/measurement-of-speed-of-static-electric-field-propagation

Comment: OK I don't understand. An electric pulse that propagates must have the form $E = f(r-ct)$? To  satisfy Gauss's law, E must be perpendicular to the pulse direction and therefore has a curl and therefore from Faraday's law generates a magnetic field. How is this avoided?

Comment: Rob it is not avoided. The magnetic field is segregated from the propagating electric field pulse by the surface of the torus, which is the geometry of the Rogowski coil: A poloidally wound toroidal coil with $B$=0 and $A$≠0 everywhere outside the minor radius of the torus.

Comment: I just discovered this is more problematic than I thought.  Two different experiments come up with two different empirical values for the speed of propagation of an electric field.  One is consistent with instantaneous propagation:

Measuring Propagation Speed of Coulomb Fields
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.2913v1.pdf

and one is finite speed:
Coulomb interaction does not spread instantaneously
http://cds.cern.ch/record/468803/files/0010036.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one has a coil, which in the steady state has a finite interior B-field, a zero B-field outside the coil, but a finite, curl-free A-field outside the coil; then you change the current in the coil rapidly: I think the following should happen.

As you say, a pulse of E-field will propagate outwards associated with the changing A-field. To satisfy Maxwell's equations:
if the pulse E-field has the form $f(kr-\omega t)$ - e.g. something like $E_0 \exp[-(kr -\omega t)^2/2\sigma]$ - then Gauss's law should ensure that the E-field is perpendicular to $r$. Furthermore, the E-field will have a curl and then through Faraday's law will have an associated, time-dependent B-field and a non-zero Poynting vector. Finally, Amp`ere's law in vacuum will yield that $\omega/k =c$, the pulse speed.

I deduce from this that the curl of the A-field does not remain exactly zero outside the coil at all $r,t$.

Comment: I've clarified my question.